# Create temporary Java object for JSON

Tags: java, javascript, json

What I want to do is create a temporary object on the fly so I can translate it to JSON and send it back to the JSP page for use by the JavaScript. FYI I'm using Java Jackson library to translate a Java Object into JSON.

The JavaBean Class for this object looks something like this.

```
public class MonthlyAnalysisBean {
    private Date monthlyProcessDate;
    private Double activeInventory;
    private Double inactiveInventory;
    private Double excessInventory;

    /* Set... Get.... Bla bla methods */
}
```

I need an object that looks like this in JSON.

```
{
    "date": "2014-04-04",
    "Active": 100.00,
    "Inactive": 10.23,
    "Excess": 2.99
}
```

Basically I just need to nicely rename and format the same fields. Is there any way to do this In Java without creating another JavaBean and creating the new object?

It would be so easy in JavaScript to just create a new object, send the JSON and be off on our merry way.

Comment: Have a look at http://jackson.codehaus.org/

Comment: ^ He said he is using that already. (Or do you want him to read something there?)

Comment: jackson, jsonlib, gson, etc... will all help you to do that rather quickly. Other approach, if you don't expect complex types, is to hand-roll a quick class that goes over the fields via reflection and creates the string.

Comment: @Kuma: tbh I must suffer from the same reading disability, I hadn't noticed either. Probably because the OP doesn't say what she's tried so far to use Jackson to reach her goal? So yes, I'd recommend to read something over there as well.

Comment: Yeah I understand, I tried to read the question atleast twice :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you don't want to "*create another Javabean*" `Map<String, String>` is an option.

You could just do

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("date", monthlyAnalysisBean.getMonthlyProcessDate());
...
```

Or try to actually use Jackson using `@JsonProperty`

```
@JsonProperty("date")
public Date getMonthlyProcessDate() { 
   return monthlyProcessDate; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Im going to look at both of these methods right now.

Comment: I went with the HashMap because I have to format the values and because I'm modifying an existing system and I don't want to edit other programmers objects.

Answer (score 0):

I've done sth like that with annotations from javax.xml.bind.annotation . I used wink library to marshal/unmarshal JAXB-annotated objects into JSON, but it's mostly for REST web services. I guess your Jackson should suite fine.

```
@XmlAttribute(name = "date")
private Date monthlyProcessDate;
```